# R - Can't reverse melt

Tags: r, casting, melt

Simple question that I couldn't solve myself (or find a solution):

```
df <- data.frame(A1 = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE), A2 = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE))
molten <- melt(df)
```

How can I reverse this and get the original df back? Neither dcast nor cast work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935706/how-to-unmelt-data-with-reshape-r

Comment: Does my answer work, or is it the case that you are already in the molten state?

Comment: It would work but as commented by user20650 - I already have the molten state without having the df.

Comment: `long <- reshape(df, dir = 'long', varying = list(1:2)); reshape(long)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you first construct and ID variable

```
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)
molten <- melt(df, id.var="id")
dcast(molten, id~variable)
```

If you are already in the molten state, notice from your example, that the rows are sorted properly. You can take advantage of this to construct an ID with `rep`:

```
molten$id <- rep(1:(nrow(molten) / 2), 2)
```

Then the `dcast` method above will work.  Of course, there may be more than two variables that were melted. You can generalize the `rep` as follows:

```
molten$id <- rep(1:(nrow(molten) / length(unique(variable))), 
                 length(unique(variable)))
```

Note that this ID creation relies on two fairly large assumptions:

1. The data creator did not sort the data in a manner that would ruin the original order.
2. Any missing values in the `melt` were not dropped.

You can partially test for the second problem using `table`. Visually check that all levels of "variable" have the same length. This is not fool proof, but is a pretty good indicator.

Comment: Thanks @user20650. I added this scenario to the bottom, though I think I'll generalize it.

Comment: Good stuff, however, I think this might run into trouble if there were uneven numbers in each group (try it after `molten <- molten[-1, ]`)
. My feeling would be to go with `ave`, and `seq_along`.

Comment: I agree. However, at that point it would difficult if not impossible to match up the observations for the "wide" operation. If the user who created the melted data dropped all NAs before we were able to see it, this operation would be dangerous. Maybe I should mention that.

Comment: The dataframe is really only a dataframe with 2 variables (one factor with 2 levels, and numerical observations) that I want to get into the wide form. Since the number of factors varies in my data (uneven!) I'm going with     `ave` and     `seq_long`

Answer (score 1):

This could be easily done with `unstack`

```
unstack(molten, value~variable)
#   A1 A2
#1  49 46
#2  51 75
#3  41 27
#4  75  4
#5  91 79
#6  19 87
#7  24 18
#8  96 57
#9  87 42
#10  8 47
```

---

Or another option is `spread` from `tidyr` after creating a sequence column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
molten %>% 
    group_by(variable) %>%
    mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
    spread(variable, value) %>% 
    select(-n)    
#      A1    A2
#   <int> <int>
#1     49    46
#2     51    75
#3     41    27
#4     75     4
#5     91    79
#6     19    87
#7     24    18
#8     96    57
#9     87    42
#10     8    47
```

Comment: First one works only with variables of equal lengths, but the second one works fine!

Comment: @GeoVogler Yes, that is right.  Your example was based on equal lengths, that is the reason I added the `unstack`