# How would I make a latex table with one set of factors as the rows and the other set of factors as the columns

Tags: r, latex

I would like to make a table in R that I can convert into Latex Code with the months as the names of the rows, and the Category as the name of the columns. In each "cell" that corresponds to a month and category, I would like to have meantotrob2 and stdtotrob2 below meantotrob2 in small parentheses. Here is what part of my dataframe looks like.

```
label Category meantotrob2 stdtotrob2
  <fct>    <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 April        1      0.122       0.361
2 April        2      0.121       0.288
3 April        3      0.123       0.297
4 April        4      0.0996      0.248
5 May          1      0.0878      0.206
6 May          2      0.0776      0.182
```

```
Months     1       2          3
# April 0.12162162 0.12111801  0.12278761
        **0.361**   **0.288**  **0.297**
# May   0.08783784 0.07763975  0.09734513
         **0.206** **0.182**   **0.259**
```

This is what I'm looking for. Standard errors are in bold.
Also, here is my head of the dataframe

```
structure(list(label = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("April", 
"May", "June", "July(1-17)", "July(18-31)", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December"), class = "factor"), Category = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2), meantotrob2 = c(0.121621621621622, 0.12111801242236, 
0.122787610619469, 0.0995575221238938, 0.0878378378378378, 0.077639751552795
), stdtotrob2 = c(0.361428596863379, 0.287914904504829, 0.297434540363719, 
0.248141256461657, 0.205954891705483, 0.181650473189414)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    label = structure(1:2, .Label = c("April", "May", "June", 
    "July(1-17)", "July(18-31)", "August", "September", "October", 
    "November", "December"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:4, 5:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: Please make your question reproducible: include a sample of your data with the output of `dput(your_data)` or `dput(head(your_data, n = 10))`

Answer (score 1):

Edited:
You are looking for an answer that needs multiple steps, you need to understand what your LaTeX table would look like first to create a data frame that looks like it to print it out as a LaTeX table.

Here's a path:

1. Melt your data.

```
melt(df,id = c("Label","Category"),variable.name = "Type",value.name = "value")
```

2. Then unmelt your data for categories: check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935706/how-to-unmelt-data-with-reshape-r)
3. Sort your data with `order`
4. Rename `Label` as `Month` using `colnames`.
5. Clear the month names from the rows that have the standard deviations.
6. Deal with the standard deviation strings with `paste` when `Type=="stdtorob2"`

```
paste0("**",as.character(foo),"**")
```

7. Remove the `Type` column because you don't need it. With `tidyverse` `df %>% select(-Type)` should do it.
8. And finally to print the table as LaTeX code using `xtable`.
   Try this:

```
library(xtable)
print(xtable(df,digits=4), include.rownames=FALSE)
```

Comment: You know how in linear regression tables they have the standard deviation below the mean? Essentially I am trying to do that.

Comment: See the edited post. You need to create a new string and print that.

Comment: Hey sorry, I updated the post with what I'm looking for since it wasn't very clear I think. I'm not trying to replicate my dataframe as a table.

Comment: value.var="value" gives an error since "value" is now a character column. not sure what I can do? as.numeric deletes the SDs

Comment: I see. Skip the first step and deal with it before deleting the Type column

Comment: Added new edits. Again, this is a multiple step question, when asking a question try to break it down to steps and look for answers that way. It will be easier for you to find an answer that way.